# Is Visual Studio Online a PaaS?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, cloud, azure-devops

This is regarding Microsoft's Visual Studio Online, I am just trying to write a paper on various Cloud Services. 
Just wanted to ask, can Visual Studio Online classified as a Platform as a Service, if not then where does it go in the cloud services area ? SaaS?
The wikipedia article does not talk about Visual Studio being a "cloud" service. But it is eing offered in Microsoft Azure.. a little confused
Thanks,
Rachit.

Comment: I would say SaaS because Visual Studio Online is a software which is offered to you as a service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio Online is a Software-as-a-Service (SaaS) offering.  The primary reasons it is classified as SaaS rather than PaaS are:

- You consume it in a per-user-license model.
- Your data is managed on your behalf by the Visual Studio Online ops team.
- You do not need to configure any "server side" features or setup virtual machines or patch operating systems (granted these last two are more IaaS than PaaS).

There are no doubt a multitude of other properties that mark VSOnine as a SaaS solution and I'm sure plenty of others will enumerate them for you :).

Comment: That's correct!  Visual Studio Online is certainly built using IaaS and PaaS resources but the end service available to customers is considered SaaS.